# Create table Using Javascript and pass data dynamically as per the given input

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, frontend, javascript-objects

my problem is company has done research and found their product sale high on particular day on particular shop.

The data:

[image]

I need to the output as like this:

[image]

I have tried solving it:

```js
let sdate = prompt("Enter Starting date : yyyy-mm-dd");
let edate = prompt("Enter Ending date :(yyyy-mm-dd");

document.write("starting date is :" +sdate);
document.write("<br><br>");
document.write("Ending date is:" +edate);
document.write("<br><br>");


let Fromdate = new Date(sdate);
let Todate = new Date(edate);

//Diff. in time between two given dates
let Difference_in_time = Todate.getTime() - Fromdate.getTime() ;
//no.of days between days
let Difference_In_Days = Difference_in_time / (1000 * 3600 * 24); 
document.write("No.of days between two dates are: " +Difference_In_Days);
document.write("<br><br>");



//checking if given dates are within one month
if( Difference_In_Days > 30 ){

    document.write("sorry, we accept upto 30days");
} else{

    document.write("Here are the results:");
    document.write("<br><br>");
    var dateArr = getDateIncrement(Fromdate,Todate);
    for (var i = 0; i < dateArr.length; i++) {
        var FinalDays = dateArr[i].getDay()/*ChangeToDay()*/;//to change given 0-6 to day's
        ChangeToDay(FinalDays);
       
}
    
}

//this function is to increment the date upto given date and put into an array
function getDateIncrement(start,end){

   var arr = new Array();
   var dt = new Date(start);
   while (dt <= end) {
       arr.push(new Date(dt));
       dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + 1);
   }
   return arr;
}
function ChangeToDay(days){

    switch(days){

   case 0:

   document.write("Sunday  -- Shop C --- Shop A --- Shop D");
   document.write("<br>");

    break;

    
   case 1:
    
   document.write("Monday  -- Shop A --- Shop B --- Shop C");
    document.write("<br>");

    
   //day(monday);
    break;


    case 2:

    document.write("Tuesday  -- Shop A --- Shop B --- Shop C  ");
    document.write("<br>");

    //day(Tuesday);
    
    break;

   
    case 3:

   document.write("Wednesday  -- Shop D --- Shop B --- Shop A");
    document.write("<br>");
    //day(Wednesday);
    
    break;


    case 4:

    
    document.write("Thursday   -- Shop D --- Shop B --- Shop C");
    document.write("<br>");
    //day(Thursday);
    
    break;


    case 5:
 
    document.write("Friday    -- Shop D --- Shop B --- Shop C");
    document.write("<br>");
    
    //day(Friday);

    break;


    case 6:

    document.write("Saturday  -- Shop E --- Shop F --- Shop D");
    document.write("<br>");
    
    //day(Saturday);
    break;

  }


}
let Output = [
    {
        day:'Monday',
        product1: "Shop-A",
        product2:"Shop-B",
        product3:"shop-c"

    },
    {
        day:'Tuesday',
        product1: "Shop-A",
        product2:"Shop-B",
        product3:"shop-c"

    },
    {
        day:'Wednesday',
        product1: "Shop-D",
        product2:"Shop-B",
        product3:"shop-A"

    },
    {
        day:'Thursday',
        product1: "Shop-D",
        product2:"Shop-B",
        product3:"shop-c"

    },
    {
        day:'Friday',
        product1: "Shop-D",
        product2:"Shop-B",
        product3:"shop-c"

    },
    {
        day:'Saturday',
        product1: "Shop-E",
        product2:"Shop-F",
        product3:"shop-D"

    },
    {
        day:'Sunday',
        product1: "Shop-C",
        product2:"Shop-A",
        product3:"shop-D"

    }
]

//function to insert table header to our program
function generateTableHead(table){
    let thead = table.createTHead();
    let tr=thead.insertRow();
    for(let key of data){
        let th=document.createElement("th");//creatin th inside tr
        let text = document.createTextNode(key); //header name inserting in the tr
        th.appendChild(text);
        tr.appendChild(th);
   
    }
}

//to generate table
function generateTable(table,data){
    for(let element of data){
        let row =  table.insertRow();
        for(key in element){
            let cell = row.insertCell();
            let text = document.createTextNode(element[key]);
            cell.appendChild(text);
        }
    }
}

let table= document.querySelector('table');
let data =Object.keys(Output[0]);
generateTableHead(table);
generateTable(table,Output);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Final Result</title>

</head>
<body>
    
    
    
    <table>
        
    </table>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="final3.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: _“please do the needful”_ - you start, please. At least we need a proper [mre] of your issue, and an actual problem description as well.

Comment: Why don't you use some library like hands on table or ag-grid they are well develop this far and provides this and further functionality out of the box

Comment: @WistonCoronell Sir, No i need this in Plain Javascript.